# Is there a .Net class to do what ManualResetEvent.PulseAll() would do (if it existed)?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is there a .Net class to do what `ManualResetEvent.PulseAll()` would do (if it existed)?

I have a need to atomically release a set of threads that are waiting on the same signal. (I'm not worried about "thread stampedes" for my intended usage.)

You cannot use a `ManualResetEvent` to do this. For example, if you do:

```
ManualResetEventSlim signal = new ManualResetEventSlim();
// ...
signal.Set();
signal.Reset();
```

Then no threads waiting on *signal* are released at all.

If you put a `Thread.Sleep(5)` between the `Set()` and `Reset()` calls, then some but *not* all of the waiting threads all are released. Increasing the sleep to 10ms allows all the threads to be released. (This was tested with 20 threads.)

Clearly it is unacceptable to be adding `Thread.Sleep()` to make this work.

However, this is easy enough to do with `Monitor.PulseAll()` and I've written a tiny class to do so.
(The reason I've written a class to do this is that we've found that the logic using Monitor, while fairly simple, is non-obvious enough to make it worth having such a class to simplify usage.)

My question is simply this: Is there a class already in .Net to do this?

For reference, here's the bare-bones version of my "`ManualResetEvent.PulseAll()`" equivalent:

```
public sealed class Signaller
{
    public void PulseAll()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
        }
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        Wait(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public bool Wait(int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return Monitor.Wait(_lock, timeoutMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    private readonly object _lock = new object();
}
```

---

Here's a sample program that demonstrates that no waiting threads are released if you don't sleep between Set() and Reset():

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _startCounter = new CountdownEvent(NUM_THREADS);

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
            {
                int id = i;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => test(id));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for " + NUM_THREADS + " threads to start");
            _startCounter.Wait(); // Wait for all threads to have started.
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine("Threads all started. Setting signal now.");
            _signal.Set();
            // Thread.Sleep(5); // With no sleep at all, NO threads receive the signal. Try commenting this line out.
            _signal.Reset();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0}/{1} threads received the signal.\n\n", _signalledCount, NUM_THREADS);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void test(int id)
        {
            _startCounter.Signal(); // Used so main thread knows when all threads have started.
            _signal.Wait();
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _signalledCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Task " + id + " received the signal.");
        }

        private const int NUM_THREADS = 20;

        private static readonly ManualResetEventSlim _signal = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        private static CountdownEvent _startCounter;
        private static int _signalledCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you use an `Interlocked` counter to keep track of how many are waiting, and then trigger an `AutoResetEvent` gate that many times? (obviously using `Exchange` down to `0` when you read the quantity)

Comment: Well, I don't really need to do that if I just use my Signaller class, which works fine (I don't need interprocess signalling) - I was just checking if I'm reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Are you releasing them at some point or would it suffice to release them automatically when ALL threads reached point X? A Barrier comes to mind ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997287.aspx )

Comment: 'Then no threads waiting on signal are released at all'.  I am very surprised at this result - are you sure?

Comment: I'm quite sure. :) I'll post the test code in a sec.

Comment: MSDN:  'When the controlling thread completes the activity, it calls Set to signal that the waiting threads can proceed. All waiting threads are released'.  You are effectively saying that a commonly-used M$ synchro API does not work.  It's an extraordinary claim/extraordinary proof thing.

Comment: I find it easier to believe that not all the threads have reached the waiting state when you set/reset the MRE.

Comment: ..and so I have to ask - what happens if you put the Sleep(10) before both the set and reset?

Comment: @Alex: That sounds interesting and I'll look into using that for new code where applicable. Most of our old code predates .Net 4, so of course Barrier wasn't available back then.

Comment: @Martin: Check my sample code. I already have a sleep of 100ms before setting the event! I could put Sleep(10000) in there, and it would STILL fail! Try it yourself. :) (Debug or release builds make no difference.)

Comment: I'm going to post my sample non-working code as a separate question, since it seems quite interesting.

Comment: An intriguing behavior (as I came to learn). I even debugged your program but was unable to find any flaw with it. My theory is that the kernel does not release all waiting threads but just sets them to runnable. Once they run they check the event again which then happens to be unsignalled. I cannot come up with a reason why it would be done this way. Clearly MRE is not made for infinitely small signalling durations.

Comment: @usr: Agreed, hence my Signaller class! :)

Comment: It sounds like a `SemaphoreSlim` (or `Semaphore`, for old .NET versions) might be what you want?

Comment: `WaitHandle`s only unblock *waiting* threads if you want to not block a thread not already waiting, you'll have to have a dialogue between that thread and the code that "sets".  e.g. code that cause "reset" must wait for all threads that should respond to the "set" to respond.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Threading.Barrier%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) object. It allows an unspecified number of Tasks to run, then wait for all others to reach that point.

And you can use it [in a way similar to WaitGroup in Go](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/using-barrier-to-implement-gos-wait-group) if you do not know which tasks from which code blocks will start to work as a specific unit of work.

Answer (score 1):

**version 1**
Maximum clarity: a new `ManualResetEvent` is eagerly installed at the beginning of each `PulseAll` cycle.

```
public class PulseEvent
{
    public PulseEvent()
    {
        mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    ManualResetEvent mre;

    public void PulseAll() => Interlocked.Exchange(ref mre, new ManualResetEvent(false)).Set();

    public bool Wait(int ms) => Volatile.Read(ref mre).WaitOne(ms);

    public void Wait() => Wait(Timeout.Infinite);
};
```

**version 2**
This version avoids creating the internal event for any `PulseAll` cycles that happen to complete without waiters. The first waiter(s), per cycle, enter an optimistic lock-free race to create and atomically install a single shared event.

```
public class PulseEvent
{
    ManualResetEvent mre;

    public void PulseAll() => Interlocked.Exchange(ref mre, null)?.Set();

    public bool Wait(int ms)
    {
        ManualResetEvent tmp =
           mre ??
           Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref mre, tmp = new ManualResetEvent(false), null) ??
           tmp;
        return tmp.WaitOne(ms);
    }

    public void Wait() => Wait(Timeout.Infinite);
};
```

**version 3**
This version eliminates per-cycle allocations by allocating two persistent `ManualResetEvent` objects and flipping between them.This slightly alters the semantics versus the above examples, as follows:

- First, recycling the same two locks means that your `PulseAll` cycles must be long enough to allow all of the waiters to clear the previous lock. Otherwise, when you call `PulseAll` twice in quick succession, any waiting threads that were putatively released by the *previous* `PulseAll` call--but which the OS hasn't had a chance to schedule yet--may end up getting re-blocked for the new cycle as well. I mention this mostly as a theoretical consideration, because it's a moot issue unless you block an extreme number of threads on sub-microsecond pulse cycles. You can decide whether this condition is relevant for your situation or not. If so, or if you're unsure or cautious, you can always use **version 1** or **version 2** above, which don't have this limitation.
- Also "arguably" different (but see paragraph below for why this second point may be provably irrelevant) in this version, calls to `PulseAll` that are deemed essentially simultaneous are merged, meaning all but one of those multiple "simultaneous" callers become [NOPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP). Such behavior is not without precedent (see ["Remarks" here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6)) and may be desirable, depending on the application.

Note that the latter point must be considered a legitimate design choice, as opposed to a bug, theoretical flaw or concurrency error. This is because *Pulse* locks are inherently ambiguous in situations of multiple simultaneous `PulseAll`: specifically, there's no way to prove that any waiter who doesn't get released by the single, designated pulser would necessarily be released by one of the other merged/elided pulses either.

Saying it a different way, this type of lock isn't designed to atomically serialize the `PulseAll` callers, and in fact it truly can't be, because it will always be possible for a skipped "simultaneous" pulse to independently come and go, even if entirely *after* the time of the merged pulse, and yet still "pulsing" before the arrival of the waiter (who wouldn't get pulsed).

```
public class PulseEvent
{
    public PulseEvent()
    {
        cur = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        alt = new ManualResetEvent(true);
    }

    ManualResetEvent cur, alt;

    public void PulseAll()
    {
        ManualResetEvent tmp;
        if ((tmp = Interlocked.Exchange(ref alt, null)) != null) // try claiming 'pulser'
        {
            tmp.Reset();                     // prepare for re-use, ending previous cycle
            (tmp = Interlocked.Exchange(ref cur, tmp)).Set();    // atomic swap & pulse
            Volatile.Write(ref alt, tmp);    // release claim; re-allow 'pulser' claims
        }
    }

    public bool Wait(int ms) => cur.WaitOne(ms);  // 'cur' is never null (unlike 'alt')

    public void Wait() => Wait(Timeout.Infinite);
};
```

---

Finally, a couple general observations. An important recurring theme here and in this type of code generally is that the `ManualResetEvent` must not be changed to the signalled state (i.e. by calling `Set`) *while it is still publicly visible*. In the above code, we use `Interlocked.Exchange` to atomically change the identity of the active lock in 'cur' (in this case, by instantaneously swapping in the alternate) and doing this ***before*** the `Set` is crucial for guaranteeing that there can be no more new waiters added to that `ManualResetEvent`, beyond those that were already blocked at the moment of swapping.

Only after this swap is it safe to release those waiting threads by calling `Set` on our (now-)private copy. If we were to call `Set` on the `ManualResetEvent` while it was still published, it would be possible for a late-arriving waiter who had actually missed the instantenous pulse to nevertheless see the open lock and sail-through without waiting for the next one, as required by definition.

Interestingly, this means that even though it might intuitively feel like the exact moment that the "pulsing" occurs should coincide with `Set` being called, in fact it is more correctly said to be right before that, at the moment of the `Interlocked.Exchange`, because that's the action that strictly establishes the before/after cut-off time and seals the definitive set of waiters (if any) who are to be released.

So waiters who miss the cut-off and arrive immediately after must only be able to see--and will block on--the event now designated for the the *next* cycle, and this true even if the current cycle hasn't been signalled yet, nor any of its waiting threads released, all as required for correctness of "instantaneous" pulsing.