# How to put many different thread to wait() and be able to awake them all with signalAll()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.5, semaphore

I've studied that in concurrent programming there's something called "event semaphore" that works like this:

Let's say "`sem`" is the event semaphore object.

Threads executing `sem.Wait()` are suspended until someone calls `sem.signalAll()` that awake any thread waiting on sem.

I can't find anything like this in C#.
The `Semaphore` class http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx is what i call a counting semaphore, and is not exacly what i need.
The `ManualResetEventSlim` http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.aspx is closer and i thought i could achive my goal by calling `set();` folowerd by `reset();` but i've read that it's not mean to be use like that and it might not awake all waiting thread.

PS, i don't know ho many waiting thread i have, i guess i could count them but i would prefere something like `signalAll()`.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.PulseAll`?

Comment: `Monitor.Wait` `Monitor.PulseAll` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but you can write one fairly simply using `Monitor`. It's easiest if you encapsulate the logic (which isn't entirely obvious):

```
public sealed class Signaller
{
    public void PulseAll()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
        }
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        Wait(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public bool Wait(int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return Monitor.Wait(_lock, timeoutMilliseconds);
        }
    }

    private readonly object _lock = new object();
}
```

Sample code using it:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _startCounter = new CountdownEvent(NUM_THREADS);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        {
            int id = i;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => test(id));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for " + NUM_THREADS + " threads to start");
        _startCounter.Wait(); // Wait for all threads to have started.
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine("Threads all started. Setting signal now.");
        _signal.PulseAll();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("\n{0}/{1} threads received the signal.\n\n", _signalledCount, NUM_THREADS);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void test(int id)
    {
        _startCounter.Signal(); // Used so main thread knows when all threads have started.
        _signal.Wait();
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _signalledCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Task " + id + " received the signal.");
    }

    private const int NUM_THREADS = 20;

    private static readonly Signaller _signal = new Signaller();
    private static CountdownEvent _startCounter;
    private static int _signalledCount;
}
```

Also see this thread: [Is there a .Net class to do what ManualResetEvent.PulseAll() would do (if it existed)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065343/is-there-a-net-class-to-do-what-manualresetevent-pulseall-would-do-if-it-exi)

Comment: Thanks it's exacly what i need. I tried using 'Monitor.Wait()' and 'Monitor.PulseAll()' but keep getting "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code." Now i undestand why.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Set` on a `ManualResetEvent` or `ManualResetEventSlim` will wake all waiting threads, provided you don't call `Reset` on it too soon after calling `Set`.

Other possibilities, depending on what you're trying to do, are [Barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx) and [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx), as well as `Monitor`, which Matthew Wilson explains quite well in his answer.